# sort column in data frame according to levels of another column

Tags: r

i'm new to R and stuck with the following data. Either i searched with the wrong terms or this question has not been risen (maybe due to simplicity?).

i have a data frame containing factors and numerical columns:

```
> head(PAMdata1)
salt cultivar  Ratiod13     StdErr
1   50     1 1.0760163 0.02915785
2  100     1 0.9814083 0.04914316
3   50     2 0.9617199 0.06571578
4  100     2 0.7878740 0.10270647
5   50     4 0.9551830 0.04134652
6  100     4 0.8429793 0.10993336

> str(PAMdata1)
'data.frame':   36 obs. of  4 variables:
$ salt    : Factor w/ 2 levels "50","100": 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 ...
$ cultivar: Factor w/ 18 levels "27","26","21",..: 7 7 15 15 13 13 11 11 9 9 ...
$ Ratiod13: num  1.076 0.981 0.962 0.788 0.955 ...
$ StdErr  : num  0.0292 0.0491 0.0657 0.1027 0.0413 ...
```

The column 'cultivar' contains factors, whose levels are ordered using another data frame:

```
PAMdata1$cultivar <- factor(PAMdata1$cultivar, levels = unique(as.character(my_other_df$cultivar)))

levels(PAMdata1$cultivar)
[1] "27" "26" "21" "52" "14" "25" "1"  "23" "7"  "8"  "5"  "28" "4"  "22" "2" 
[16] "53" "51" "50"
```

What i would like to have is PAMdata1$Ratiod13 ordered by the levels of cultivars. How do i transform the vector of levels into a vector of line numbers each level is located in?

I would appreciate any help on this.

Thanks a lot

Comment: this? `PAMdata1[order(PAMdata1$cultivar), ]`

Comment: If you solve your problem, post it as an answer and then accept it, rather than edit it into your question.

Comment: Exactly. I didn't know that factors are by default ordered by the order of their levels. Embarrassing...

Comment: @Thomas: Thanks for the advice. I will do it in 8h. My reputation is rather low and i'm not yet allowed to answer my own questions that rapidly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

talking to an office mate and seeing your comments i saw my confusion between sort() and order()

```
PAMdata1[order(PAMdata1$cultivar),]
```

or even

```
PAMdata1[with(PAMdata1,order(cultivar)),]
```

would do the job.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

A data.table option would be to setkey cultivar:

```
setkey(PAMdata1,cultivar)
```